# Type annotating for ndb.tasklets

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mypy

GvRs App Engine [ndb Library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/async) as well as [monocle](https://github.com/saucelabs/monocle) and - to my understanding - modern Javascript use Generators to make async code look like blocking code.

Things are decorated with `@ndb.tasklet`. They `yield` when they want to give back execution to the runloop and when they have their result ready they `raise StopIteration(value)` (or the alias `ndb.Return`):

```
@ndb.tasklet
def get_google_async():
    context = ndb.get_context()
    result = yield context.urlfetch("http://www.google.com/")
    if result.status_code == 200:
        raise ndb.Return(result.content)
    raise RuntimeError
```

To use such a Function you get a `ndb.Future` object back and call the get `get_result()` Function on that to wait for the result and get it. E.g.:

```
def get_google():
    future = get_google_async()
    # do something else in real code here
    return future.get_result()
```

This all works very nice. but how to add type Annotations? The correct types are:

- get_google_async() -> ndb.Future (via yield)
- ndb.tasklet(get_google_async) -> ndb.Future
- ndb.tasklet(get_google_async).get_result() -> str

So far, I came only up with `cast`ing the async function.

```
def get_google():
    # type: () -> str
    future = get_google_async()
    # do something else in real code here
    return cast('str', future.get_result())
```

Unfortunately this is not only about `urlfetch` but about hundreds of Methods- mainly of ndb.Model.

Comment: Aren't the results casted automatically if you work with entities? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entities

Answer (score 1):

`get_google_async` itself is a generator function, so type hints can be `() -> Generator[ndb.Future, None, None]`, I think.

As for `get_google`, if you don't want to cast, type checking may work.

like

```
def get_google():
    # type: () -> Optional[str]
    future = get_google_async()
    # do something else in real code here
    res = future.get_result()
    if isinstance(res, str):
        return res
    # somehow convert res to str, or
    return None
```

Comment: so whenever I write `future.get_result()` I have to do some kind of type inference magic? I can't teach mypy & co what `future.get_result()` will return `Optional[str]`? :-(

Comment: ```ndb.Future``` itself not always return Optional[str], so it is natural to define type hint in each function, maybe...? Like the case you mentioned ```ndb.Model```. count_async().get_result() returns int, not str, for example.